# iOS8/Simulator - error in SFHFKeychainUtils, SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain error -34018

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, sfhfkeychainutils

I have just downloaded XCode 6 and adjusted my application to run under it.

It seems to work just fine, however I use `SFHFKeychainUtils`, and when I run the application in the simulator I get the error:

```
error getting UUID: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain error -34018.)
```

Looking at the code, I'm not quite sure why I would get that error.  I also do not get that error running my application on an iOS7 device running from XCode6, just the simulator, so I think it's an iOS 8 error.

Any thoughts on resolving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 34018. It happens when client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements.

iOS 8 is BETA version and doesn’t support Keychain Access developer APIs on the simulator at the moment.

[iOS 8 beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to check the release notes for that.